# Magento 2: Translate Order Email template

Tags: magento2, email-templates, translate

**How can I translate the attribute label?**

I've already added to "Manage Label" but still not working.

Color is translated but not size?
[image]

Does anyone have an idea ? I tried all possible by placing in my_theme/i18n.de_DE.csv still not working.